# Помогите разобраться с выводом дерева

Tags: дерево, php

Есть функция вывода дерева, написанная мной процентов на 50, остальное пришлось искать как делать. Нашел, но не могу уловить логики. Вот скрипт:

```
    <?php
        function make_tree(){
            mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "password") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks";
            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while($node = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                $nodes[$node['id']] = $node;
                $keys[] = $node['id'];
            }

            foreach($keys as $key){
                if($nodes[$key]['parent_id'] == 0)
                    $tree[] =& $nodes[$key];
                else
                    $nodes[$nodes[$key]['parent_id']]['nodes'][] =& $nodes[$key];
            }
            return $tree;
        }
    ?>
```

Может ли мне кто-нибудь объяснить логику при переборе массива, т.е. то, что происходит в foreach. Я не понимаю за счет чего дочерний элемент попадает именно к своему родителю. Желательно понятным языком, т.к. еще новичок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($keys as $key){ // перебрать все ключи найденных элементов (см. while)
    if($nodes[$key]['parent_id'] == 0) // если id родителя = 0, то у нас главный эл.
        // делаем на него ссылку в массиве $tree
        $tree[] =& $nodes[$key];
    else // иначе, если id родителя отличается от 0
        // добавляем ссылку на эл. в массив $nodes[родитель_id]['nodes']
        $nodes[$nodes[$key]['parent_id']]['nodes'][] =& $nodes[$key];
}
```

В конце концов вам вернут `$tree`, в котором будут родительские элементы с подмассивами `nodes`, в которых будут дочерние.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, а зачем делать именно ссылку, а не просто присваивать?

Comment: Чтобы вот это сразу добавляло и дочерние элементы в ``$tree``:

    $nodes[$nodes[$key]['parent_id']]['nodes'][] =& $nodes[$key];

Comment: Все равно не улавливаю мысль. Я не понимаю, почему дочерний элемент идет именно к своему родителю... Ну, тоесть, например, у нас есть вот такое дерево:
id = 1
   parent_id = 1
   parent_id = 1
   parent_id = 1
id = 2
   parent_id = 2
   parent_id = 2
   parent_id = 2
id = 3
   parent_id = 3
   parent_id = 3
   parent_id = 3

Я не могу понять, почему, допустим, parent_id = 2 идет именно как дочерний элемент id = 2, и почему он не попадает, скажем к id = 1?

Comment: Если мы определяем ``id`` родителя, в который попадет запись исходя из её ``parent_id``, то как запись с ``parent_id=2`` может попасть куда-нибудь кроме как к записи с ``id=2``?